# Issue animating ui based on reducer state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a `react` project for visualizing `insertion sort` using `redux`. I am using `react-redux` to create and handle `actions`. However, the problem is that in my `insertionSort` algorithm, I dispatch an `updateArray` action every time the `array` being sorted changes. I put `print` statements inside the reducer and saw that the state was in fact changing and the action was being dispatched correctly, however, my actual `array` does not re-render. I put `prints` inside the relevant UI component's `render()` function and saw that it was only being called once or twice rather than every time the reducer receives the action. I tried restructuring my code multiple times and reading about similar problems that people have had but their answers did not help me.

Am I just structuring this the wrong way? Should I not be using dispatches every second or so to update my array?

> I have a `main.js` file which is used to render the UI components including my array:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
     setArray = () => {
         this.props.setArray(50, window.innerHeight / 1.4)
     startSort = () => {
         this.props.startSorting(this.props.algorithm, this.props.array)
     }
     render() {
         let { array} = this.props
         return (
             <div>
                 <Navbar
                     startSort={this.startSort}
                     setArray={this.setArray}
                 />
                 <MainWrapper>
                     <Row />
                 </MainWrapper>
             </div>
              )
          }
      }
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
         array: state.array,
      }
  }

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
         setArray: (length, height) => {
              let array = Array.from({ length: length }, () =>
              Math.floor(Math.random() * height))
              dispatch(setArray(array))
         },
         startSorting: (algorithm, array) => {
              var doSort
              if (algorithm == 'insertionSort') {
                  doSort = insertionSort
               }
              doSort(array, dispatch)
       }
     }
  }
```

> My actual array is generated with `Row.js`

```
class Row extends React.Component {
    generateNodes(array) {
        var elements = []
        array.forEach((value, index) => {
            elements.push(
                <CenteredColumn>
                    <ArrayNode idx={index} value={value} />
                </CenteredColumn>
            )
        })
        return elements
        }
    render() {
        let { array } = this.props
        console.log('UPDATED ARRAY: ' + array)
        var arrayElements = this.generateNodes(array)
        return <RowWrapper>{arrayElements}</RowWrapper>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        array: state.array
    }
}
```

> And finally, my actual algoritm is in `insertionSort.js` in which I import my actions from their reducers and pass in a dispatch function from `main.js`:

```
function delayedInsertion(array, dispatch) {
let n = array.length
var i = 0
function loop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var temp = array[i]
        var j = i - 1
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > temp) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j]
            j--
        }
        array[j + 1] = temp
        // console.log('ARRAY: ' + array)
        dispatch(updateArray(array))
        i++
        if (i < n) {
            loop()
        }
    }, 200)
}
loop()
console.log('DONE')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mutating your state.

You are passing `this.props.array` to your `doSort` action and as I understand your idea correctly, you are just calling `delayedInsertion` from that action (you did not post source code of that action).
But in `delayedInsertion` you are mutating the passed array when you are changing positions of you items, here:

```js
while (j >= 0 && array[j] > temp) {
   array[j + 1] = array[j]
   j--
}
array[j + 1] = temp
```

You need to perform immutable change of the array.